# Proving $V / U \cong W$ for complementary subspaces $U, W$ without using the dimension formula

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $U,W \subseteq V$ be disjoint subspaces of $V$ such that $U+W=V$. How can it be shown that $V / U \cong W$ without using the dimension formula(e)? 
I've seen that fact used in a equivalence proof between the different dimension formulae, but I don't know how to prove it without proving the dimension formulae first. I guess it comes down to finding an explicit basis of $V / U$ but I don't quite know how to do that.

Comment: @Bernard The quotient space, I had the slashes the wrong way round.

Comment: $U$ and $W$ are not "disjoint", rather write "$U\cap W=\{0\}$". The obvious isomorphism is $w \mapsto w + U$; it's linear, injective (by the above) and surjective (due to $U+W=V$)

Comment: Find a projection map from $V$ to $W$ and show that the kernel is $U$.

Comment: This is just a basic application of the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas "[...] without using the dimension formula(e) [...]"

Comment: What do you mean by "the dimension formula"? The proof of the first isomorphism theorem doesn't involve any dimension formula. It shows explicitly that the map $v(\ker\varphi)\mapsto\varphi(v)$ is a vector space isomorphism $V/\ker\varphi\to\operatorname{Im}\varphi$ for any homomorphism $\varphi\colon V\to W$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way is proving that the restriction to $W$ of the quotient projection is injective and surjective (onto $V/U$). It's really just some definition-fu, where you use $U\cap W=\{0\}$ and $U+W=V$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Consider the map:
\begin{align}
p\colon V&\longrightarrow W,\\
v&\longmapsto w\enspace\text{if }\; v=u+w.
\end{align}
Show $p$ is well-defined, and it is linear surjective. What is its kernel?